# Losing smtp/pop3/imap access

Tags: osx, router

I have a server running OS X. This server connects to another server, this other one CentOS 6.3, from times to times to collect mail messages over POP3/IMAP and also to send mails using SMTP (exim, on that server).

After half a day working well, suddenly this OS X loses the ability to connect using IMAP/POP3/SMTP to the other server over the web but it can access the other server using HTTP/HTTPS/FTP and all other protocols.

This OSX server is behind a router installed by the ISP, without a known brand (probably OEM from another company). When the problem happens, I reboot that router and the OSX machine can access the server again.

What can be wrong? Is OSX saturating the router for some reason? Is the router broken? How can I trace the origin of this nasty problem?

Comment: Log into the router (telnet/ssh/http/...) and check logs. If no logging enabled, enable and wait and check.

Comment: I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a firewall issue. To debug your issue a little bit more I'd look to temporarily turn off your OSX firewall.

I found instructions for doing this [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Turn-off-Mac-Firewall).

#### General Steps (10.6 - Snow Leopard)

1. Click on the Apple menu from your toolbar.
2. Select System Preferences.
3. Choose View, then select Security when the System Preferences window appears on your screen.
4. Click on the Firewall tab.
5. Select the Stop button to disable your firewall. "Firewall Off" will now be displayed above the button.

I wouldn't operate too long this way but it may be helpful in eliminating the firewall as the potential source of your issue.

Comment: never had OSX firewall on. It is always off. The router has a firewall.

Comment: What kind of router is it?

Comment: good question. Like I said in my question, this router was installed by the provider. It is a gigabit ethernet router. It is clearly an OEM router. The initial page says Thomson TG799vn.